# Intruiging Symmetric harmonic sum $\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{H^{(k)}_n}{n^k}\, = \frac{\zeta{(2k)}+\zeta^{2}(k)}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I proved the following equation

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}  \frac{H^{(k)}_n}{n^k}\, = \frac{\zeta{(2k)}+\zeta^{2}(k)}{2}$$

We define

$$H^{(k)}_n=\sum_{m= 1}^n \frac{1}{m^k}$$

I am looking forward to seeing what approaches would you use .

Comment: You case is a special case of the more general case [B(p,q)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275643/proving-an-alternating-euler-sum-sum-k-1-infty-frac-1k1-h-kk/276590#276590).

Comment: Yes, but the general case has no closed form ! The evaluation of the multiple integrals might be impossible

Comment: Just to be clear, you are asking for others to prove this identity, right, to see if they approach it the same way or some novel and surprising way?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews exactly, please tell me if this is against the rules here !

Comment: No, that sort of question is okay, but it is always good to include an actual "question" in your question, to make it clear what you are asking. "How would you prove this?" "I am looking forward,..." sounds like a side-musing.

Comment: Could you work your proof a little more?

Comment: This is a special case of a more general formula .Proving it would take several papers !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Isn't this just 
$$\begin{align}
\zeta^2(k) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^km^k} \\&= 2\sum_{1\leq m\leq n} \frac{1}{(nm)^k} - \sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n^k)^2}\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^k}\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{m^k} - \zeta(2k)\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n^{(k)}}{n^k} - \zeta(2k)
\end{align} $$?

You could also figure that:

$$\zeta^2(k) = 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_{n-1}^{(k)}}{n^k} +\zeta(2k)$$
Every rearrangement here can be done due to absolute convergence.

Comment: very nice . I did not know it is that easy.

Comment: Hey, if you are interested , can you solve the following http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459973/generalized-alternating-harmonic-sum-sum-n-geq-1-frac-left1-frac12-f?rq=1 for p is odd .