# A cubic nonlinear Euler sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers, euler-sums

Any idea how to solve the following Euler sum

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{H_n}{n+1}\right)^3 =
>  -\frac{33}{16}\zeta(6)+2\zeta(3)^2$$

I think It can be solved it using contour integration but I am interested in solutions using real methods.

Comment: Summation by parts driven by $$\begin{eqnarray*}H_{n+1}^{3}-H_n^3 &=& (H_{n+1}-H_n)\left[(H_{n+1}-H_n)^2+3 H_{n} H_{n+1}\right]\\&=&\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}+\frac{3 H_n^2}{(n+1)}+\frac{3 H_n}{(n+1)^2}\end{eqnarray*} $$ maybe?

Comment: Are there similar such, maybe easier, known identities ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus, see http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/FlSa98.pdf

Comment: Here you go: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/311703645_Evaluation_of_a_cubic_Euler_sum

Comment: @tired, thanks very nice.

Comment: @tired, this sum was solved by Cornel Ioan Valean before Ramya Dutta. see https://www.researchgate.net/publication/317144592_jca-10-101

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
S&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{H_n}{n+1}\right)^3=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{H_{n-1}}{n}\right)^3\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^3}{n^3}-3\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2}{n^4}+3\sum_{n=1}^\infty
\frac{H_n}{n^5}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^6}
\end{align}

Substituting the following results:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^3}{n^3}=\frac{93}{16}\zeta(6)-\frac52\zeta^2(3)$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n^2}{n^4}=\frac{97}{24}\zeta(6)-2\zeta^2(3)$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^5}=\frac74\zeta(6)-\frac12\zeta^2(3)$$

We get $$\boxed{S=2\zeta^2(3)-\frac{33}{16}\zeta(6)}$$

Note that the first and second sum are proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3299882) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3240815/prove-sum-n-1-infty-frach-n2n4-frac9724-zeta6-2-zeta23) respectively. As for the third sum, can be obtained using the Euler identity.