# Prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(3)}}{n^2}=\frac{227}{48}\zeta(6)-\frac32\zeta^2(3)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

How to prove this advanced harmonic series of weight 6?

> $$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(3)}}{n^2}=\frac{227}{48}\zeta(6)-\frac32\zeta^2(3)$$
>   where $H_k^{(p)}=1+\frac1{2^p}+\cdots+\frac1{k^p}$ is the $k$th generalized harmonic number of order $p$.

This result can be found in the book ***Almost impossible integrals, sums and series*** page $414-419$ using pure series manipulations but can be done in different ways?

I will post my approach soon.

Answer (score 2):

Using the fact that
 $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n^{(3)}x^n=\frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(x)}{1-x}$$
Divide both sides by $x$ then integrate, we get

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n^{(3)}x^n}{n}&=\int \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(x)}{x(1-x)}\ dx=\int \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(x)}{x}\ dx+\underbrace{\int \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(x)}{1-x}\ dx}_{IBP}\\
&=\operatorname{Li}_4(x)-\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_3(x)+\int\frac{\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{x}\ dx\\
&=\operatorname{Li}_4(x)-\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_3(x)-\frac12\operatorname{Li}^2_2(x)+c
\end{align}
Set $x=0$, we get $c=0$.

Therefore

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n^{(3)}x^n}{n}=\operatorname{Li}_4(x)-\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_3(x)-\frac12\operatorname{Li}^2_2(x)\tag{1}$$

Now multiply both sides of $(1)$ by $-\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}$ then integrate, we get
\begin{align}
S&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n^{(3)}}{n}\int_0^1 -x^{n-1}\ln(1-x)\ dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n^{(3)}}{n}\left(\frac{H_n}{n}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n^{(3)}H_n}{n^2}\\
&=-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_4(x)}{x}\ dx+\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_3(x)}{x}\ dx+\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}^2_2(x)}{x}\ dx\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^4}\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\ln(1-x)\ dx+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^3}\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\ln^2(1-x)\ dx-\frac16\operatorname{Li}^3_2(1)\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^4}\left(-\frac{H_n}{n}\right)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^3}\left(\frac{H^2_n}{n}+\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n}\right)-\frac16\zeta^3(2)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^5}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H^2_n}{n^4}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H^{(2)}_n}{n^4}-\frac{35}{48}\zeta(6)
\end{align}
By substituting:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^5}=\frac74\zeta(6)-\frac12\zeta^2(3)$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n^2}{n^4}=\frac{97}{24}\zeta(6)-2\zeta^2(3)$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_k^{(2)}}{k^4}=\zeta^2(3)-\frac13\zeta(6)$$

we get the closed form
$$\boxed{S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(3)}}{n^2}=\frac{227}{48}\zeta(6)-\frac32\zeta^2(3)}$$

**Note**: The first sum can be found using Euler identity, the second sum is evaluated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3240815/prove-sum-n-1-infty-frach-n2n4-frac9724-zeta6-2-zeta23/3295379?noredirect=1#comment6778662_3295379) and the third sum is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3238703).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my slight variation on how I go about things. As you will see, the ideas used and results found are almost the same as yours.

I will make use of result (1) you kindly provide in your answer, namely

> $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H^{(3)}_n x^n}{n} = \operatorname{Li}_4 (x) - \ln (1 - x) \operatorname{Li}_3 (x) - \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Li}^2_2 (x)\tag1$$

Since
$$\int_0^1 x^{n - 1} \ln (1 - x) \, dx = -\frac{H_n}{n},$$
one can express the sum as
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n H^{(3)}_n}{n^2} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H^{(3)}_n}{n} \cdot \frac{H_n}{n} = -\int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1 - x)}{x} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H^{(3)}_n x^n}{n} \, dx\tag2$$
Substituting (1) into (2) leads to
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n H^{(3)}_n}{n^2} &= - \int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1 - x) \operatorname{Li}_4 (x)}{x} \, dx + \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 (1 - x) \operatorname{Li}_3 (x)}{x} \, dx\\
& \qquad + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1 - x) \operatorname{Li}^2_2 (x)}{x} \, dx\\
&= -I_1 + I_2 + \frac{1}{2} I_3.
\end{align}

---

**The first integral** $I_1$

\begin{align}
I_1 &= \underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1 - x) \operatorname{Li}_4 (x)}{x} \, dx}_{IBP \,\, 3 \,\, \text{times}}\\
&= -\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left [\frac{\zeta (4)}{n^2} - \frac{\zeta (3)}{n^3} + \frac{\zeta (2)}{n^4} + \frac{1}{n^4} \int_0^1 x^{n - 1} \ln (1 - x) \, dx \right ]\\
&= -\zeta (4) \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} + \zeta (3) \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3} - \zeta (2) \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4} + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^5}\\
&= -\zeta (4) \zeta (2) + \zeta^2 (3) - \zeta (2) \zeta (4) + \frac{7}{4} \zeta (6) - \frac{1}{2} \zeta^2 (3)\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \zeta^2 (3) - \frac{7}{4} \zeta (6),
\end{align}
where the results
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^5} = \frac{7}{4} \zeta (6) - \frac{1}{2} \zeta^2 (3) \quad \text{and} \quad \zeta (2) \zeta (4) = \frac{7}{4} \zeta (6),$$
were used.

---

**The second integral** $I_2$

In this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3240815/prove-sum-n-1-infty-frach-n2n4-frac9724-zeta6-2-zeta23/3295379#3295379) I showed that
$$I_2 = 2 \zeta (3) \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^2} - 2 \zeta^2 (3) - 2 \zeta (2) \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^3} + 2 \zeta (2) \zeta (4) + 2 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H^2_n}{n^4} - 2 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^5}.$$
All four of the sums appearing in the above expression for $I_2$ are known. The first, second, and fourth sums are standard Euler sums while a proof of the third sum can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3240815/prove-sum-n-1-infty-frach-n2n4-frac9724-zeta6-2-zeta23/3295379#3295379). The results are:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^2} &= 2 \zeta (2)\\
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^3} &= \frac{5}{4} \zeta (4)\\
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^5} &= -\frac{1}{2} \zeta^2 (3) + \frac{7}{4} \zeta (6)\\
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H^2_n}{n^4} &= \frac{97}{24} \zeta (6) - 2 \zeta^2 (3),
\end{align}
 Thus
$$I_2 = -\zeta^2 (3) + \frac{89}{24} \zeta (6).$$

---

**The third integral** $I_3$

\begin{align}
I_3 &= \underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1 - x) \operatorname{Li}^2_2 (x)}{x} \, dx}_{IBP}\\
&= -\operatorname{Li}^3_2(1) - 2 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1 - x) \operatorname{Li}^2_2 (x)}{x} \, dx\\
\Rightarrow I_3 &= -\frac{1}{3} \zeta^3 (2) = -\frac{35}{24} \zeta (6).
\end{align}

---

**The main sum**

Combining the results found for the above three integrals, for the sum one has
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n H^{(3)}_n}{n^2} = \frac{227}{48} \zeta (6) - \frac{3}{2} \zeta^2 (3),$$
as required.

Comment: Nice. Regarding $I_3$ , the derivative of $Li_2(x)$ is already there so no need for IBP.