# Evaluating sums of the form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^a}\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{1}{m^b}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to tackle infinite sums of the type $$S(a,b)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^a}\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{1}{m^b}$$
where $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers. Zeta function is involved, for example $S(3,2)=3\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{9}{2}\zeta(5)$, but so far I can't figure out how to relate them.

Comment: For completeness, would you please indicate where your equality for $S(3,2)$ comes from? Thanks

Comment: From there, I guess : [Wiki : multiple zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_zeta_function) .

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerSum.html

Comment: Mathematica, actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my knowledge there is no general formula for

> $$S(p,q) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H^{(p)}}{n^q}$$

Where

> $$H_n^{(p)} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^p}$$

**We have some formulas for special cases**

- If $p$ is even and $q$ is odd or the other way around see [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11139-007-9089-6).
- If $p=1$ we have

> $$S(1,q)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^q}= \left(1+\frac{q}{2}
>  \right)\zeta(q+1)-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{q-2}\zeta(k+1)\zeta(q-k)
> $$

*The proof  [Generalized Euler sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469023/generalized-euler-sum-sum-n-1-infty-frach-nnq)*

- Symmetric formula

> $$S(p,q)+S(q,p) = \zeta(p+q)+\zeta(p)\zeta(q)$$

*See the proof [here](http://advancedintegrals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/advanced-integration-techniques.pdf) page 106*

- For  $p=q=k$

> $$S(k,k) = \frac{\zeta(2k)+\zeta^2(k)}{2}$$

*The proof [Intruiging Symmetric harmonic sum $\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{H^{(k)}_n}{n^k}\, = \frac{\zeta{(2k)}+\zeta^{2}(k)}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463861/intruiging-symmetric-harmonic-sum-sum-n-geq-1-frachk-nnk-fra)*

- For small order $p,q$ Usually we consider the generating function

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty H^{p}_k x^k = \frac{\mathrm{Li}_p(x)}{1-x}$$

*See the proof [here](http://advancedintegrals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/advanced-integration-techniques.pdf) , page [97] .*

- Relate it to integration through

> $$S(p,q) = \zeta(p)\zeta(q) - \frac{(-1)^{p-1}}{(p-1)!}\int^1_0
>  \frac{\log^{p-1}(x) \mathrm{Li}_q(x)}{1-x}\,dx$$

*The proof is page 4 in PEDRO FREITAS paper on integrals of polygarithmic functions [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0406401.pdf).*

- There also exists a complex analysis approach usually for

> $$S_{p^r,q}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(H_n^{(p)})^r}{n^q}$$

*by Philippe Flajolet and Bruno Salvy [here](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/FlSa98.pdf).*

Comment: (+1) Excellent Explanation. You may add 
$$
S(p,q) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n}^{(p)}}{n^q} = \zeta(p)\,\zeta(q) - \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\zeta(p,n+1)}{n^q}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Apparently I have not made enought internet search. Seems like this is thoroughly investigated question.